# From Azure Function (secured by AAD), how to properly detect the caller (the end-user of SPFx WebPart) through the AadHttpClient?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, user-profile, azure-ad, azure-functions

***Note:**
Both Azure Function and the SPFx WebPart mentioned below are written in **NodeJS/JavaScript**. None of them are in C#.*

I have an Azure Function (secured by AAD: App Registration) which is being called by `AadHttpClient` via SPFx WebPart on a SharePoint page. The SPFx codes look like this:

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
    this.context.aadHttpClientFactory.getClient("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX") // <--- This is the AAD Client App Id.
    .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        
        client.post("https://myAzureFunctionName.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1", AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: someData
            })
        })
        .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((response: any): void => {
            console.log("SUCCESSFUL API RESPONSE:", response); // <--- At this point, I get the respond back from the Azure Function, successfully.
            resolve();
        }, (err: any): void => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    }, err => reject(err));
});
```

It is working fine **except** from the Azure Function end, I don't know how to properly detect who/which current **SharePoint User** is calling this API. The only dirty trick I can use is, of course, to attach the User Information, such as *Email Address*, (retrieved from [_spPageContextInfo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-get-user-properties-and-user-information-list) object) into the `AadHttpClient` API call, to the Azure Function.

### Question

- Is there a proper/authentic way where I can detect the caller (the currently logged in, end-user of SPFx WebPart) through the AadHttpClient, from the Azure Function end? So that I can use the user's Email Address further in the Azure Function.

Appreciate the helps in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- You can obtain identity details using *ClaimsPrincipal* object.
- The most straightforward method is to obtain the *ClaimsPrincipal* object from the Function's binding parameters.
- Include the *ClaimsPrincipal* as an additional parameter in the function signature.
- The object will be automatically injected, similar to how ILogger is injected.
- Sample code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Security.Claims;

// DEMO: Get ClaimsPrincipal as a binding parameter
namespace ClaimsDemo.Function
{
    public static class ClaimsDemo
    {
        // Pass ClaimsPrincipal parameter in the function signature
        [FunctionName("ClaimsDemo")]
        public static IActionResult Run
            ([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
             HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal claimIdentity)
        {
            log.LogInformation("User ID: " + claimIdentity.Identity.Name);
            
            log.LogInformation("Claim Type : Claim Value");

            foreach (Claim claim in claimIdentity.Claims)
            {
                log.LogInformation(claim.Type + " : " + claim.Value + "\n");
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

**User Claims from the Request Headers**

- App Service passes user claims to the app by using special request headers.

```
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID --User ID
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME --User Name
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-IDP --Identity Provider's ID
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL --Claims
```

```
//Extract User ID and Claims from the request headers
var principal_name = req.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"].FirstOrDefault();
var principal_Id = req.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"].FirstOrDefault();
string easyAuthProvider = req.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-IDP"].FirstOrDefault();
string clientPrincipalEncoded = req.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL"].FirstOrDefault();
```

- Similar thread present at below link

  [User Identity in Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587136/how-to-get-current-user-identity-in-azure-function-with-azure-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the helps. I guess yours are C# codes while I'm a TypeScript/JS person. But I'll try to find the TypeScript equivalent to your codes and see if the approach works. Will let you know later. Thanks again.

Comment: You can access the user details using request header  properties. use property mentioned in below comment

Comment: X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID --User ID
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME --User Name
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-IDP --Identity Provider's ID
X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL --Claims

Comment: Hi @Rajat, reading the request headers worked! I can see the user's principle id and Email Address using (X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID and ID X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME) headers! Not sure how secure is this approach. BUT IT SIMPLY WORKS OUT OF THE BOX! THANK YOU!!! (You can post this as a new Answer or edit your answer above, so that I can mark it as accepted answer!)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a call to the SharePoint REST API or the Microsoft Graph to get the full user profile in your Azure Function.

REST: `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties`

Graph: `/me`

To get the bearer token needed to make the call to get the user profile, you use the `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` method. You can do this using the following C# code inside your Azure Function. I don't know how to do the equivalent in Node.js.

```
var tenantName = "your tenant name";
var impersonationToken = req.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

var clientId = "app client Id";
var clientSecret = "app client secret";
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(impersonationToken);

var azureApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

var scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
var authResult = await azureApp.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion)
    .ExecuteAsync();
var token = authResult.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Hi @Rob Windsor, thank you for helping out. Afaik, calling to REST or Graph APIs `/me` as a user requires Bearer Token, right? May I know how do I seek for logged user's Bearer Token from the Azure Function point of view, please?

Comment: I updated my answer with the code to get the token